# Space between constant hash and bracket causes undefined method error

Tags: ruby, methods, constants, local-variables

This works fine:

```
hsh = { a: 'str' }
hsh [:a] # => "str"
```

This works as well:

```
HSH = { a: 'str' }
HSH . fetch(:a) #  => "str"
```

This doesn't:

```
HSH = { a: 'str' }
HSH [:a] # >> NoMethodError (undefined method `HSH' for main:Object)
```

Why is this the case?
And is this documented anywhere?

---

I'm fiddling around with vertical alignment so if you have this:

```
var0 = VERTICAL_ALIGN[GREAT]
var1 = IS_VERY       [GREAT]
```

You know what's it supposed to do since you have the first line.

But this one works(as well):

```
var0 = VERTICAL_ALIGN[GREAT]
var1 =        IS_VERY[GREAT]
```

Comment: @sawa is it not obvious that the OP simply wants to know why they got an error calling the key value on the constant with a space but not on non-constant object?

Comment: @lacostenycoder At least, it is not written. And you are guessing.

Comment: Regarding good/bad/required style comments: even if this worked, this is still terrible style. When reading code, how do you know whether `a [b]` means `a[b]` or `a([b])`?